# merge strings from details section to 1 word

Tags: string, merge, crystal-reports, concatenation, formula

in the crystal report i want to merge the words inside details per group into 1 word only and i need to display it on header but running total functions seems can't do it.

### like this example here

1 Deer
1 Fox
1 Dog

2 Bear

3 Panda 
3 Horse

into

## Deer, Fox, Dog

## Bear

## Panda, Horse

but each line will be displayed in each page header
i have only encountered those formulas in crystal report where you will create 3 formulas and put the 3rd on footer section or details section but if you put it on header it only produce 1 word

Comment: can you post formula?

Comment: i don't have formula for this currently i am only adding all words to make it one but some words are not needed in one page and it is needed in the other page so merging them in the stored procedure is not applicable